# Redux Form - multiple update function renders slow

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form 7.2.0.

In my Project , I have 30 Fields in my form.

Based on the First Field Value , i need to update some 20 fields. i call change action creator for 20 times. it takes more time to render these 20 fields. very slow.

is there any way to make it fast in render?

or

is there any way to update multiple fields in single action?

please help me to rectify this

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: https://github.com/Subash48/reduxformegs -  not slow in rendering.. but  render function called 20 times

Comment: I don't see 30 fields in a form in this.

Answer (score 1):

Really the only correct answer is to use an additional middleware provider.  See [`dispatch multiple actions from Redux action creators`](http://jamesknelson.com/can-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-from-redux-action-creators/) to get an idea of the pros and cons.

You could set a flag somewhere in your state tree when the first field changes, avoid rendering via `shouldComponentUpdate` until all fields have been updated, then when everything has been updated, set that flag back.

The only other way I could think about handling this would be using the [`reducer.plugin`](https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/docs/api/reducerplugin.md/) to make a larger state change, but I think this is a dangerous path that could easily break in the future and just not behave in a predictable manner.

Currently batch field changing is not supported by [`redux-form`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2118) or [`redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/959#issuecomment-151446296) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use initialize action provided by redux form.
There are two ways to use this:

1. https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/ Initialize it when creating a form, like they did in the example.
2. Pass 'initialize' action as prop and call to update all the fields with one action call.

   ```
   const data = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
   this.props.initialize(data);
   ```

   Just make sure to match the field names with keys in data object.
   This will fire one action and all fields will be initialized.